# Razor page will not render is IIS10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, iis-10

ASP.NET application works fine in Visual Studio but after publishing to Windows server 2012/IIS10 I receive the following error attempting to run the app via IE
The file "/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.]

Is this a code issue or IIS configuration problem or ??

Here's the _Header.cshtml...

```
<div id="header" class="page-header">
    <img src="~/Images/CCIT.png" />
    <font class="page-header">Cow Creek Band of the Umpqua Tribe of Indians</font>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you publishing to a site's root? Or a subfolder?

Comment: Hi mxmissle (hah, my father was an engineer assigned to guidance for the MX or Peacekeeper or whatever they're calling it this year) Anyway I am publishing directly under default web site as an application.

Comment: Nice catch, very few recognize (or even remember) the program. They usually think its a mx (motocross) thing. Are you 100% sure `_header.cshtml` is deployed to that location?

Comment: _header.cshtml is under wwwroot/EDTMVC/Views/Shared.

Comment: try changing your reference to `_header.cshtml` to  `~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml`

Comment: Thanx, MX. I just figured that out before I saw your post. Great minds think alike! Giving you credit for the fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your reference to `_header.cshtml` from `/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml` to `~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml`.